# How to push apart the first two natural frequencies of a cantilever beam

Tags: frequency-response, modal-analysis

We have first two natural frequencies of a composite Cantilever Beam obtained through experiment and analytical calculation.

Experiment gives 31 and 250 Hz
whereas formulae give 30 and 200 Hz.

ANSYS also matches analytical results but as can be seen, the experiment's 2nd freq is quite far from analytical or FEA results.

Need help or suggestion which parameter can influence the gap in the values of the two frequencies

Comment: what is the error on the physical measurements? How will that affect the calculations?

Comment: It is 2nd Frequency coming different from analytical one. Despite repetitive tests result is same. Cant call it an error. 
Question is just to know the parameter that influences just 2nd Freq and not 1st one.

Comment: It is very unusual for a test to come in stiffer than the theoretical result. How did the static deflection compare?  How confident re you in the material properties, layup orientation in particular.

Comment: @Solar Mike, typically the frequency is measured using an FFT analyser, and the frequency calibration of them is spot on. However, a poor test method could shift the frequencies. (I'm not going to give an exhaustive list)

Comment: @GregLocock I'm talking about the physical measurements of the beam ie for the length etc - what is the error? will it change with temperature? A theoretical beam can be stated easily to be 4m long and it will be exactly so, but a real beam delivered to site for the experiment - will it be exactly 4m or +/- 1mm or 0.5mm or 0.001mm? How much will that change the results? I was just making the point to see if the OP had considered that...

Comment: @Rehan Jamshed  can you describe both the test procedure and the test object in more detail? It looks as though you have a tapered beam as the frequency ratio for a uniform beam is 6.26, yours is higher in both cases.

Comment: @GregLocock I will check the static deflection results ...

Comment: @GregLocock beam is UD E-glass epoxy with all layers in 0 direction and total thickness being 1.5 mm, width 40 mm and free length 150 mm. 
The fixed end was almost 150 mm length held in a clamp.

Comment: What sort of excitation was used? Did you model the clamp as well as the beam? How much did the accelerometer weigh? What did the test results look like? What signal processing parameters were used? What is the proportion of glass to epoxy?

Comment: Your FEA and your calculation and the test all give the wrong ratio of frequencies for a uniform cantilever.

Comment: @GregLocock
No. The beam is not tapered. 
Accelerometers was very light 3 gm in weight, placed close to free edge whereas beam weighs 15 gm. 
Impact hammer excitation was used and FFT was performed to get frequencies. 
Ratio of Glass to Epoxy was 50-50. (Vacuum bagging)

Comment: so you used an accelerometer that was 20% of the mass of the beam? Don't you think that will have some effect? A good way to check is to put a second acceleromter alongside the first and see what difference that makes.So, we still have the puzzle that the ratio of the frequencies, second /first, is wrong.

Comment: @GregLocock    
Yes mass of Accelerometer does affect the beam's results but my question is different. My question is what influences the "gap" between the first two Modal Frequencies

Comment: I suggest you FEA the beam with the mass of the accelerometer in place and see what the frequencies are. My other question would be what the rotational stiffness of the clamp is. You still haven't explained why the ratio of the frequencies is wrong in the hand calculation.

Comment: @GregLocock    
Sure. I will add mass of Accl. in FEA. My question still stands unanswered while doing hand calc or FEA we have F1: 30 Hz and F2: 200 Hz. I just want to increase the gap between the two values "analytically" without making the beam tapered

Comment: Those are the wrong frequency  ratio for a uniform beam. If you add mass at the  node of the second then it will affect the frequency of the first mode, but not the second mode. If you stiffen the beam at the antinode near the wall of the second mode it will affect the frequency of the second mode but not the first, very much. if you add mass there it will decrese the frequency of te second mode by more than the first mode. https://vlab.amrita.edu/?sub=3&brch=175&sim=1080&cnt=1

Comment: @GregLocock.   F1 at 31 and F2 at 200 Hz are analytical ones without the effect of addition of Nodal mass or stiffening. 
Why are we getting Freqs at such ratio analytically if they are wrong ?

Comment: I gave you a link to a document with numbers that look right. What equation are you using that gives the wrong result?

Comment: The link you provided is not opening. 
The eq. is F1 = (1.875^2/2piL^2) * (Sqrt(EI/Rho*A)) ....F2 = (4.694^2/2piL^2) * (Sqrt(EI/Rho*A))